# how to make use of Javascript variable which are defined on index.html/index.jsp to Vue.js?

Tags: javascript, jsp, vue.js, vuejs2

I am new to Vue.js, I developed a Vue.js app using terminal, now, I built it and place it on java web application. If I run as it is, then it's working fine.

> But I need to pass csrftoken to Vue.js. To do so, I started working by setting `Vue.prototype.$csrfToken = '*************************';` statically. Now, it should be dynamic and must come from the java response session.

I tried to define a global variable in index page like - `var token = '<%= request.getSession().getAttribute("token") %>';` and assign this variable in Vue.js file like: `Vue.prototype.$csrfToken = token;`.

This is not working. How to accomplish such?

Answer (score 0):

I guess, the issue is with your environment. Here a checklist to find the error:

- Make sure the javascript code `var token = '****'` is in your html source code (caching or a bug might get in the way)
- Obviously, check if no errors occur during `token` initialization or `Vue.prototype` modification
- Check if `Vue.prototype.$csrfToken = token;`  is called after global variable initialization: your script with Vue might be included before the global variable being set.

And I should add that the pattern you're using is not encouraged: see the official [Vue docs](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/cookbook/adding-instance-properties.html#When-To-Avoid-This-Pattern) over the usage of Instance Properties

Comment: if I alert then token initialization place popout first